# Фильтр таблицы по списку дат

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется таблица `large_table` с колонками `some_id, some_date, много-других колонок...` и список пар `(my_id, my_date) == (123, '2017-01-01'), (345, '2016-05-05), ...`. В каком виде этот список непринципиально (текстовый файл, временная таблица). Для каждой пары (my_id, my_date) из списка мне нужна 1 строка таблицы, согласно запросу:

```
SELECT * TOP(1) FROM large_table
WHERE some_id = my_id AND some_date < my_date
ORDER BY some_id DESC
```

Т.е. строка с нужным `some_id` и максимальной датой не позднее `my_date`

Я могу сделать запрос типа:

```
SELECT * FROM large_table
INNER JOIN #temp_table
ON some_id = #temp_table.my_id AND some_date < #temp_table.my_date
ORDER BY some_id, some_date
```

и потом отфильтровать из вывода нужные строки внешним скриптом.

Можно ли получить нужное одним запросом?

Comment: добавить в запрос `row_number() over(partition by some_id order by some_date desc` обернуть еще в один запрос и там наложить на эту новую колонку условие =1

Comment: @Mike спасибо за ссылку, похоже то, что нужно